# ArrayList to String Without the spaces in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I am trying to convert this `ArrayList` to a `String`, but don't want the spaces between the numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

String NumberRightString = "";
String ButtonText = "";

public void OnClick (View v) {

    Button button = (Button) v;

    String ButtonText = button.getText().toString();

    arrayList.add(ButtonText);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Object obj : arrayList) {
        sb.append(obj.toString());
        sb.append("\t");
    }

    String NumString = sb.toString();

    NumString.replaceAll("//s","");

    textView.setText(NumString + "/" + number);
}
```

This does not work and the spaces are still there. Please help me!

Comment: Change `"//s"` to `"\\s"`.

Comment: @saka1029 that did not work

Comment: Change  NumString.replaceAll(" ","");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace

```
NumString.replaceAll("//s","");
```

to

```
NumString = NumString.replaceAll("\\s","");
```